# Scoping of variables in a for loop

Tags: loops, go, scope

The following program manipulates two arrays. The algorithm is of little importance except to note that the array tmp gradually gets smaller.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func arrayToString(a []int, delim string) string {
    return strings.Trim(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(a), " ", delim, -1), "[]")
}

func numSeries(arr []int) ([]int, []int) {
    return arr[:2], arr[2:]
}

func main() {
    highnum := []int{8,7}
    tmp := []int{6,5,4,3,2,1}
    curr := []int{}
//    fRight := ""
    for i, v := range highnum {
        curr, tmp = numSeries(tmp)
        fmt.Printf("v %d numSeries result curr %s tmp %s\n", v, arrayToString(curr, ", " ), arrayToString(tmp, ", " ) )
        fmt.Printf("final (1) %s\n", arrayToString(tmp, ", " ) )       
//        fRight += "[" + arrayToString(append(curr, v), ", ") + "]"
        if i == len(highnum)-1 {
            fmt.Printf("final (2) %s\n", arrayToString(tmp, ", " ) )
        }
//        fmt.Printf("fRight |%s|\n", fRight)        

    }
}
```

The results are:

```
v 8 numSeries result curr 6, 5 tmp 4, 3, 2, 1
final (1) 4, 3, 2, 1
v 7 numSeries result curr 4, 3 tmp 2, 1
final (1) 2, 1
final (2) 2, 1
```

The program works - final (1) and final (2) comments in the output have the same value. However, if I uncomment the three commented-out statements above I get an incorrect result. Here is the incorrect program and the result.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func arrayToString(a []int, delim string) string {
    return strings.Trim(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprint(a), " ", delim, -1), "[]")
}

func numSeries(arr []int) ([]int, []int) {
    return arr[:2], arr[2:]
}

func main() {
    highnum := []int{8,7}
    tmp := []int{6,5,4,3,2,1}
    curr := []int{}
    fRight := ""
    for i, v := range highnum {
        curr, tmp = numSeries(tmp)
        fmt.Printf("v %d numSeries result curr %s tmp %s\n", v, arrayToString(curr, ", " ), arrayToString(tmp, ", " ) )
        fmt.Printf("final (1) %s\n", arrayToString(tmp, ", " ) )       
        fRight += "[" + arrayToString(append(curr, v), ", ") + "]"
        if i == len(highnum)-1 {
            fmt.Printf("final (2) %s\n", arrayToString(tmp, ", " ) )
        }
        fmt.Printf("fRight |%s|\n", fRight)        

    }
}
```

Result:

```
v 8 numSeries result curr 6, 5 tmp 4, 3, 2, 1
final (1) 4, 3, 2, 1
fRight |[6, 5, 8]|
v 7 numSeries result curr 8, 3 tmp 2, 1
final (1) 2, 1
final (2) 7, 1
fRight |[6, 5, 8][8, 3, 7]|
```

Note that final (1) and final (2) comments have different values. This is wrong. I suspect this type of behaviour is entirely correct and I am falling for a beginner's 'gotcha'. I'd be grateful if somebody could point out an existing StackOverflow question that gives a solution, or describes what is going on. I'd be especially happy to see a reference to the official language definition covering this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is here:

```
fRight += "[" + arrayToString(append(curr, v), ", ") + "]"
```

In particular, `append`. The key here is that slices are views on arrays. The `curr` and `tmp` point to the same underlying array, `curr` being the beginning part of it and `tmp` being the end. The way `append` works is that if the slice has sufficient capacity, it will simply add the element to the end of the slice and increase the `len`. When you run that `append`, `curr` has sufficient capacity, so `v` is added to the end of `curr`, which happends to be the first element of `tmp`. So you overwrite that element.

Comment: It is one thing to learn the theory, and another to actually use it in the real world. A great lesson for me personally.